# Как правильно запустить контейнер mysql в Docker для Laravel 8*x

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-8

Есть файл `docker-compose.yml` следующего содержания:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./docker/nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
            - php-cli
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php-fpm
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_enable=1"
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - mysql

    php-cli:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php-cli
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            XDEBUG_MODE: "coverage"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - composer:/root/.composer/cache
        depends_on:
            - mysql

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - mysql:/var/www/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        ports:
            - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
        networks:
            - backend

#    postgres:
#        image: postgres:13.3
#        volumes:
#            - postgres:/var/www/lib/postgresql/data
#        environment:
#            POSTGRES_USER: "admin"
#            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "YkDdkAoF"
#            POSTGRES_DB: "cabinet-ul"
#        ports:
#            - "5432:5432"

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin:latest
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        networks:
            - backend
        depends_on:
            - mysql

volumes:
    composer:
    mysql:
#    postgres:

networks:
    backend:
#        ipam:
#            driver: default
#            config:
#                - subnet: 172.25.0.3/24
```

и файл `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DATABASE_URL=${DB_CONNECTION}://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_DATABASE}
```

Информация о контейнерах:

```
source_mysql_1        docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
source_nginx_1        nginx -g daemon off;             Up       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
source_php-cli_1      docker-php-entrypoint php -a     Exit 0
source_php-fpm_1      docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       9000/tcp
source_phpmyadmin_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
```

Проект Laravel запустился и даже работает, с phpmyadmin тоже всё норм захожу и что-то там делаю под root-ом но вот когда я пытаюсь авторизоваться в своём приложении выходит ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = kra@mail.ru limit 1)
```

Весь день я потратил на чтении документации и разных статей но ничего не помогло (видимо плохо читал) и отчаявшись найти решение я решился написать сюда, надеюсь вы мне поможете и расскажите что я делаю не так.

Это мой первый опыт работы с Docker-ом так что будьте полегче )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включите сервисы php-fpm, php-cli, nginx в единую сеть:

```
networks:
  - backend
```

Добавьте в environment mysql сервиса переменную:

```
MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
```

И лучше не использовать подключение к БД из приложения с привилегированным пользователем root и не устанавливать одинаковые пароли для root и рядового пользователя.

После добавления выполните команду:

```
docker-compose down -v && docker-compose up -d --build
```